# Beginners / Advance ebook and video toturial on sound engineer

Tags: audio, tutorial, engineering

I am actually new the process of being a sound engineer, and i have been managing event like birthdays but i still need some tutorial  that will guide me to an advance level. Please  any help will be very useful. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I've often found that the manuals for many sound boards can be pretty instructive in terms of explaining what controls do and what the proper use of them is,  at least as a very basic introduction, though the quality does vary from manufacturer to manufacturer and based on if it is a more entry level board or a higher end professional targeted board.  If you want something for a more in-depth read, Handbook for Sound Engineers is pretty well regarded, though a bit pricy.

Comment: +1 for that and you're right about varying quality; the manual for my Yamaha 01X is a perfect example of how to utterly baffle the end user. =)

Comment: At the audio engineering school I attended, we spent the first few months learning how to read console schematics/block diagrams, before even touching the equipment.  At the time it was torture lol, but in hindsight, I can't imagine a better way to grasp sound-as-an-electrical-signal.

Answer (score 2):

There are too many different aspects to sound engineering to cover in a single tutorial. Having said that, there are numerous resources that can help you along the way.

For recording, a great, free resource is Brandon Dury's book: [Killer Home Recording](http://www.recordingreview.com/blog/news/free-audio-recording-guide/). 
There are also numerous videos on youtube touching on subjects such as room acoustics, standing waves, etc.

For live work there are lots of things to consider but one that crops up reasonably often is room feedback. [Here's a guide to reducing it for any given room](http://joetastic.hubpages.com/hub/Eliminating-Feedback-An-Audio-Professionals-Guide-to-Ringing-Out-a-Performance-Space).

If you can afford it, some formal sound engineering training at your local college can be invaluable (depending upon the quality of the course - I was lucky enough to attend a good one).

If cash is a bit too tight for that, I can also personally recommend [Audio Masterclass](http://www.audiomasterclass.com). It's a distance learning course - not everyone's cup of tea but I took the course a few years ago and found it to be both useful and informative, with the added bonus of being reasonably cheap (about £150 when I did it).

Hope some of that can get you started and good luck!